# css in a media query is not getting applied

Tags: html, css, media-queries

edit: solved it. i accidentally left a media query in the  middle of the css that i meant to delete. also fixed up some errors. thanks yall. works.

So I have a bunch of html and css code that works fine. Then I add 2 media queries in the css, in each query I add a little bit of code that will override some of the other css. None of this media query code works though. Here's my media query stuff:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 975px){
    body .top_outermost_container {
      width: 976px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-height: 485px){
    .bottom_bar {
        top: 445px;
        bottom: auto;
    }
}
*/
```

Im putting the whole code up here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CJgqI Thanks for takin a looK! you rock. For real. By the way you might have to copy and paste the code to a text editor to get the browser rendering up to good quality. THANKS AGAIN

Comment: do you really mean `max-height`?

Comment: Using firebug is a good idea for this sort of thing as it allows you to see what styles are being applied from where. It could be something to do with how specific your targeting of styles is as to whether the over-ride works.

Comment: There a quite a few mistakes in your mark-up too `div`s not closed, a few missing `>` etc..

Comment: your  @media screen and (max-width: 975px) and (max-height: 438px)

is not closed...

Comment: THANK YOU SHINOV T. FIXED it

Answer (score 2):

It looks like is the issue you're speaking on is you never close off your first @media query. `@media screen and (max-width: 975px) and (max-height: 438px){` needs a "}". The 2nd query won't fire because it can't be a child of another. So on line 228, or so, you need a closing "}" just before the `@media screen and (max-width: 975px){` query. BUT there are other issues as well.

Your errors seem to be coming fromt he HTML where you'd need to close your tag ">"

```
Line 15: <div class= "top_contained_container" </div>
Line 39: <div class="bottom_list_container1" </div>
Line 49: <div class="bottom_list2" </div>
```

Using a Validation tool such as http://html5.validator.nu/

you also have a few errors in your CSS like extra close tags "}"

```
Line 114: body {overflow: hidden;}}
```

where you can find these easier are via validation tools as well: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator

Answer (score 0):

That trailing `*/` looks like it might be a problem.

Your syntax looks fine, it should work.